# What is an efficient way to split a multidimensional array into a set of arrays based on a value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like the following:

```
Array (

       [0] => stdClass Object (
                [name] => StackOverflow
                [image] => CanHelp.jpg
       ) 

       [1] => stdClass Object (
                [name] => AnotherObject
                [image] => SecondImage.jpg
       ) 
)
```

How can I arrange/split this array into groups based on the first letter of [name]?

i.e. There are about 1,000 items in this array, which I have already ordered alphabetically by [name], however I want to be able to have groups that begin with 'A', 'B', etc.

Like this, for 'A' and 'S':

```
Array (

       [0] => stdClass Object (
                [name] => AnotherObject
                [image] => SecondImage.jpg
       ) 

       [1] => stdClass Object (
                [name] => AndAnother
                [image] => notImportant.jpg
       )
)

Array (

       [0] => stdClass Object (
                [name] => StackOverflow
                [image] => CanHelp.jpg
       )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$split = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $split[$item->name[0]][] = $item;
}
```

Comment: almost perfect! thanks! one more thing - is it possible to group non-alphabetic chars into one array? e.g. [0]? including numbers and other chars.

Comment: @samb Sure. The logic is simple enough to extend. :P

Comment: `foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ( preg_match('/[a-z]/', $item->name[0]) ) $split[$item->name[0]][] = $item;
    else $split['other'][] = $item;
}`

Comment: @roselan cheers - make it '/[A-Za-z]/' and it's what I wanted!